Devextreme - Set up custom directives for dxi-item or DxSimpleItem
I have a custom v-my-directive directive that I want to apply to an dx-item/dxsimpleitem.
On normal html elements it works
<h1 v-my-directive>This is a Headings</h1>

but on an DxSimpleItem it does not work
<DxSimpleItem v-my-directive data-field="FirstName"/>

The application that I am working on is quite dynamic so i dont want to specify the editor types the whole time that is why DxSimpleItem or DxItem works best.
Seems like the directives also works on dx-textbox and the other editor types just not on the 2 that i want to use.
Is there something i am missing?
I have attached an example
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-haibt-s6t9hj?file=%2FApp.vue
